# login/session management. Android/php server

Tags: android, session, authentication, oauth-2.0

I would like to manage Login/registration between android app and a server (php+mysql). I'm looking for a solution which allow the user to login just one time and then, since the session is valid, stay logged even if He will close the app and open it again. Something similar to facebook and google login. I read something about OAuth2 and It seems to do what I'm looking for but I'm not able to find a good tutorial for php(server)/android part. Any suggestion? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two important things need to implement for your requirement i.e.

1) Login success flag stored to sharedPreferences
2) Token Validation

write a php api to validate login user and return the success flag i.e. valid login or not. On mobile side - if successful login triggers then store the success flag at sharedPrefernces

Token validation - when user successfully logins to the system then php api returns the login success flag with unique token and last access date and time everytime when it hits to login service.
every time when you are hitting to any php api you have to pass the token and lastaccessdate to php api. php api validates it by token matching and lastaccessdate with currect server date and perform an minus operation between them. if you want to keep login validate for 7 days to validate according to it.

Comment: I agree with you..but..If I install the app on another device..or I change the password by another device..how I can manage the situation?

Comment: if you installs the app on another device and login then you will get the fresh token and latest lastaccessdatetime .. so on previous device where app is already logged in stop functioning. and fresh login device will starts working.

Comment: almost all google,facebook uses the same login methodology...above logic is well tested. so implement this

Answer (score 0):

Save your status in shared preferences or SQite database

Comment: what i'm looking for is a guide..serverside and android side. Furthermore, how can  I manage the session? when should I invalidate it? which is the best way to do it?